# Loading image in Flutter | Path from content root doesn't work, but absolute path works

Tags: flutter, image, directory, path

Very simple app, the image is in project/images folder.

1. When I try to load it from the relative path:
   **'images/diamond.png'**

the image doesn't load.

2. When I do it from the absolute path: **'/Users/MacBookAir/StudioProjects/secondtry_iamrich/images/diamond.png'**

it does.

Why is this? Can anyone please help?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('I am Rich'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage('images/diamond.png'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

This is the error it is providing:

```
======= Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: images/diamond.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:237:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:658:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "images/diamond.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#99cb5(), name: "images/diamond.png", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not forgot to add image folder path to your `pubspec.ymal` folder like

```
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/icons/
    - assets/loader.json
```

[image]

Use this plugin in your android studio it will auto generate your all assets no need to write path.

Use it like this

```
Image.asset(Assets.imagesNoDataFound)
```

Comment: I installed it and it's still not working

Comment: please provide pubspec.ymal code

Comment: Found the problem. Thanks Ravin. As absurd as it sounds, the problem was in the indentation... Anyway, it would be good to install well the FlutterAssetsGenerator
because (as a newbie) I didn't really understand the following two steps. It is already correctly installed.

1. Define your assets in Dir
2. Build -> Generate Assets class
Alt/Opt + G
It will generate assets.dart on lib/generated.

Comment: Thanks @RavinLaheri.
 Asset Generator helps me to build UI faster and scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment and change the asset section in your pubspect.yaml file can fix it.

```
  assets:
    - images/
```

Comment: Nothing, it doesn't work. I've uploaded the problem with the error it is providing